# How to Find special Characters in a column with like in excel macros

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am facing problem while searching for special characters in a column in excel vba.
I used the like operator as follows:

```
If Sheets("Eclipse Report").Cells(j, k).Value Like "*[%, !, *, ;, :, ~, °, ß, ö , ô, ó, ò, Ç, ü, é, â, ä , à, å, ç, ê, ë, è, ï, î, ì, æ, Æ, ô, ö, ò, û, ù, ÿ, ¢, £, ¥, ƒ, á, í, ó, ú, ñ, Ñ, °, o, ·, ², €, Ÿ, ©, ®, À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å, È, É, Ê, Ë, Ì, Í, Î, Ï, Ð, Ò, Ó, Ô, Õ, Ö, ×, Ø, Ù, Ú, Û, Ü, Ý, Þ, ã, ð, õ]*" Then    
    Sheets("Eclipse Report").Rows(j).Select
    'Sheets("Eclipse Report").Rows(j).Copy
    'Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    'Sheets("Sheet3").Paste
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
    Rows(j).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
    Rows(j).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Sheets("Sheet3").Select

    'Sheets("Sheet3").Paste
    'MsgBox ("special record found and pasted")

    Exit For
End If
```

The code is not finding the records I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the spaces from the character list, it passed my test.

```
Sub Test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Dim r As Range
    With Sheets("EclipseReport")
        Set r = .Range("A1:O1")

        For j = 1 To 255
             r(j) = Chr(j)
        Next

        For j = 1 To 17
            For k = 1 To 15
                If .Cells(j, k).Value Like "*[%!*;:~°ßöôóòÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìæÆôöòûùÿ¢£¥ƒáíóúñÑ°o·²€Ÿ©®ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞãðõ]*" Then
                    .Cells(j, k).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Update:  As Comintern stated the commas weren't necessary either.

Comment: Hi @thomas , thanks for your answer and kind help. But still i am not getting the correct output . cells which have not any special character are displaying with yellow, which is not the expected output. Can you pls suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

The problems with your `Like` like pattern is that the bracketed character list does not have delimiters.  So to match `a`, `x`, and `z`, you would need to use `[axz]`, not `[a, x, z]`.  The second pattern will match `a`, `x`, `z`, `,` and space.

So, the pattern you're looking for is:

```
Like "*[%!*;:~°ßöôóòÇüéâäàåçêëèïîìæÆôöòûùÿ¢£¥ƒáíóúñÑ°o·²€Ÿ©®ÀÁÂÃÄÅÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞãðõ]*"
```

However, keep in mind that `Like` is sensitive to locale settings and your text compare option (see the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251796.aspx)).

Personally, I'd consider using a VScript RegExp instead - they're a bit easier to work with and have much more pattern flexibility.

Comment: My answer was already accepted but I removed the commas from the character list as you stated.  Thanks +1